# Swift protocols with generic collections

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, collections

I want to have a protocol that contains a collection of `Item`. The goal is for it to not matter if the collection of `items` is an array/set/etc, as long as it conforms to `Collection`.

```
protocol Content {
    var items: Collection<Item> // This doesn't work, swift doesn't support generic protocol parameters
}
```

An example use case, where I use Realm to persist Content, but would like to be able to mock data without needing to import Realm:

```
// Typical usage with Alamofire and Realm

struct RealmArticle: Object, Content {
   var items = List<Item>()
}


func fetchContent(completion: (Content?, Error) -> ())) {
   session.request(...).responseDecodable { (content: RealmArticle) in 
      completion(content, nil)
   }
}

// Mock without needing to include Realm

func mockFetchContent(completion: (Content?, Error) -> ()) {
   completion(MockArticle(items: (0...5).map { Item() }), nil)
}

struct MockArticle: Content {
    var items: [Item]
}
```

My current solution is to use an array in the protocol, and modify the realm model:

```
protocol Content {
    var items: [Item]
}

struct RealmArticle: Object, Content {
   // I have to use a List because that is what the Realm SDK requires.
   var _items = List<Item>()

   var items: [Item] { Array(_items) }
}
```

But this isn't ideal because it loads the entire `List` into memory whenever `items` is accessed. Is there a better solution or should I take a different approach?

Edit:

**Update in regards to associated types:**

1. <del>There is no way to constrain/enforce the collection type when using `associatedtype`</del>.
2. Objects that implement the protocol have to be generic, which is very cumbersome. Especially if the model has several collections of different types.
3. The parent object containing `Content` would also have to be generic. For example:

   ```
   protocol Content {
       associatedtype A: Collection
       associatedtype B: Collection
       // etc

       var items: A
       var otherItems: B
       //etc
    }

    struct Parent<C: Content> { 
        var content: C?
    }

    struct RealmArticle<Item, OtherItem, etc>: Object, Content {
      var items: Item
      var otherItems: OtherItem
      // etc
    }

    var article = RealmArticle<List<Item>, List<OtherItem>, etc>()
    var parent = Parent<RealmArticle<List<Item, List<OtherItem>, etc>()
   ```

**Edit 2: Correction**

The collection can be constrained to other **protocol** or **class** types by specifying the `Element`. This gets it a little closer to what I need:

```
protocol Content {
    associatedtype C: Collection where C.Element: Item
    var c: C { get set }
}
```

However it still requires the protocol to be used as a constraining type rather than being able to use it directly:

```
struct Parent<C: Content> {
    var content: C?
}
```

What would be ideal but doesn't compile:

```
protocol Item {
    var id: String { get }
}

protocol Content {
    associatedtype C: Collection where C.Element: Item
    var items: C { get set }
}

struct Parent {
    // Protocol 'Content' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    var content: Content?
}

let parent = Parent()

// Both classes conform to content so swapping should be possible. 
// It is possible if I don't use associated types and just use an array
parent.content = RealmArticle()
parent.content = MockArticle()
```

If this is not possible in Swift, or is bad code design, I would really appreciate an explanation as to why. Other languages support this, there are legitimate use cases for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live without the requirement that the element of the collection must be `Item` then you can use `associatedtype` to make it work with `Collection`

```
protocol Content {
    associatedtype T: Collection
    var items: T { get set }
}
```

This should be enough to be able to mock as you want.

Comment: Upvoted because this could be useful info for others, but in my case I need to know the type

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a stand-alone protocol when you could just make this method generic?

```swift
func fetchContent<C: Collection>(completion: (Result<C, Error>) -> Void) where C.Iterator.Element == Object {
   …
   }
```

**UPDATE**

As per the discussion we had in the comments below, I'd recommend adopting the approach used in this [article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/mocking-in-swift/), hence mocking the service from which you get the content.

**2nd UPDATE**

It's not really clear what are your needs: for example in regards to the `Content` protocol you are defining, you're not either specifying the mandatory property items access. Is it a `{ get }` property?

```
protocol Content {
    var items: [Item] { get }
}
```

Then your `RealmArticle` conformance doesn't need a double storage, since `List` is a collection:

```
protocol Content {
    var items: [Item] { get }
}

extension RealmArticle: Content {
   var items: [Item] { Array(_items) } 
}
```

Is it a `{ get set }` property? Then you might as well be able to add the conformance by being also able to create a `List` from a `Sequence`, hence not needing the double storage:

```
protocol Content {
    var items: [Item] { get set }
}

extension RealmArticle: Content {
   var items: [Item] { 
       get { Array(_items) }
       set { _items = List(newValue) /*or whatever way you create a List collection from a a sequence of Items*/ }
    } 
}
```

As in regards of Swift Generics, you might as well constraint the `associatedtype` too with a `where` clause:

```
import Foundation

protocol Content {
    associatedtype C: Collection where C.Element: Hashable
    var c: C { get set }
}

struct MyContent: Content {
    var c: Array<Int> = []
}

var myC = MyContent()
myC.c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Types conforming to a generic protocol might also constrain the generic associated type of the protocol either implicitly (as in the earlier example), explicitly and conditionally:

```
struct AnotherContent<T>: Content where T: Hashable {
    var c: Array<T>
    
}

let myA = AnotherContent(c: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

struct YetAnotherContent<C: Collection>  {
    var c: C
}

extension YetAnotherContent: Content where C.Element: Hashable {}
    
}
```

Maybe you want to review a bit Swift Generics, and better understand how they work.

**3RD UPDATE**

Your last problem can be solved by adopting a type-erased `AnyContent` concrete type. You might as well find many resources online explaining this pattern, here's [one](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasure-in-swift/).
As per the reason behind the need of this pattern, that'll be cause Swift is strongly-typed language thus everything needs to resolve to a concrete type at compile time; other languages you've mentioned in the comments below (as in Obj-C) are weakly-typed hence you might as well resolve a type at run-time.
Anyway there have been also additions to the Swift language lately, (especially because of SwiftUI `View` protocol) in regards to [opaque types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) which might be useful to have knowledge about when it comes to write code using generics and protocols with an associated type.

Comment: `Content` is not a collection, it's a single object that can hold collections

Comment: `Content` is just a wrapper of a `Collection` in your case, it doesn't provide any functionality hence is just redundant.

Comment: It's simplified to showcase the problem. In reality the model holds more data than just a single collection.

Comment: Is `List` conforming to `Collection` ?

Comment: Yes, it is conforming

Comment: Then you can use that as a constrain on the generic methods.

Comment: Yes that is what Joakim is essentially suggesting, ie define a constraint against Collection in the protocol. However, it's not very elegant, especially if I have multiple collections with different types in the model.

Comment: Joakim gave the right answer for that problem: you have to have an associated type constrain if you want to use a generic collection in that protocol. 
Now what I'm trying to understand is what are you trying to achieve: do you need a mock for testing content fetches from an hypothetical web service? Then maybe you'd have to come up with a different solution, perhaps one which sees the fetch method getting injected with the service. You'll then inject a mock service for testing.

Comment: That solution works but requires compromise on type information. I asked the question because parameterized generic collections are a feature in many other languages. I was hoping there was a solution in swift that I was missing, but from what you're suggesting it sounds like Joakim's suggestion is the only way to do so.

Comment: Please check the article I've linked in my updated answer, I'm sure you'll find some insights in regards to mocking for tests. There are also some more articles on that blog that are related on unit testing and could suit your needs or at least point you to a solution you'd find adequate and also elegant.

Comment: Thank you. However, there are use cases for this other than mocking, e.g. using the Facade pattern to abstract and develop against interfaces. I updated my question to explain why I don't think associated types achieves the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: I've updated my answer too. It seems you haven't grasped at all Swift Generics. But as I stated earlier, it's not just that: I think you should review your approach to mocking for testing in terms of dependencies, and that comes before closing a design pattern appropriate for the work at hand.

Comment: I'm using a List<> because that is what Realm requires using (it's a reactive database). Realm is optimized so that the collection is lazily loaded, so you can query for one item without needing to load the entire List into memory. If I convert that to an array `Array(_items)`, it loads the whole list into memory, so I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: I understand how generics work. I don't think I'm explaining the problem clearly enough. Your associatedtype example doesn't work when I try to use Content in another object, or another protocol, without having to specify the generic types:
`struct ParentObject {
    var content: Content?
}`

Comment: I've just used that code in a Swift playground before posting my answer, and everything works.
And yes, it's not clear what you need to test hence what to mock and even if mocking is the right way to go; or if adopting protocol oriented approach is correct rather than a closures based approach or even a subclassing approach.

Comment: Once again you are using `Content` protocol in a wrong way: it has an `associatedtype` as `Collection` does. Or would you be able to write `struct Parent { var array: Array }`, the compilers asks you: `Array` of what?
So in your case you should stick to either a generic approach or a specialised one: `struct Parent<T> { var array: Array<T> }` or `struct Parent { var array: Array<Int> }`. The same will apply to Content: `struct Parent<C: Content> { var content: C }` or specialising with a concrete type: `struct Parent { var content: MyContent }`

Comment: I understand a generic is required in that case, but that's the issue. Trying to swap between objects that hold different collections doesn't work without the parent object being a generic, even though both objects conform to the protocol. If I use an array instead of a generic collection it works. This feature is possible in other languages, including ObjC, so I guess at this point Im just wondering why it's not available in Swift, is it by design or a limitation? But perhaps that a topic is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: In any case, this discussion was much appreciated, upvoted for your insights.

Comment: In Obj-C you can do that cause it's a weakly typed language, while swift is a strongly-typed one: hence at compile time everything must resolve to a concrete type. So it could be seen as a feature or as a limitation depending on your opinion in regards to these two approaches. Anyway for the latter case you've specified there is the type-erasure pattern: you basically create a wrapper concrete type specialized on the associatedtype of the protocol.